# How can I use tableRef.onRowSelected to update the UI via the onRowClick property?

Tags: material-table

I've written an `onRowClick` function to change the rows `tableData.checked` value when the row is click as seen in the answer here #300

I can see the checked state updating in a console log but the checkbox itself does not change visibly until I actually click another rows checkbox. It will then show all the checkboxes that had their `tableData.checked` values updated. I'd like to be able to have the checkbox actually display this change to the user onRowClick.

Here is my current code:

```
<MaterialTable
          onRowClick={(event, rowData) => {
            console.log(event.target, rowData);
            console.log(
              "Row Selection State Before: " + rowData.tableData.checked
            );
            rowData.tableData.checked = !rowData.tableData.checked;
            console.log(
              "Row Section State After: " + rowData.tableData.checked
            );
          }}
         options={{ selection: true}}
/>
```

**This is the state of the UI on my first row click:**

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-04 at 2 32 27 PM]

**Console Log on first row click:**

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-04 at 2 32 46 PM]

**UI After selecting one checkbox (clicking directly on the checkbox of another row):**

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-04 at 2 34 32 PM]

**Console Log after clicking the initial row again:**

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-04 at 2 35 23 PM]

Is there any way to make sure the UI updates for the MaterialTable component without resetting anything when the `checked` state is updated programmatically?

I've also gotten tableRef.onRowSelected working properly but the UI still doesn't re-render with the rows checkbox selected.

[Here is the codesandbox with the fix I've attempted](https://codesandbox.io/embed/white-moon-zx814)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this one out with some help from @orestes22 in the official material-table Gitter chat.

Add tableRef to state:

```
state = {
  tableRef: React.createRef(),
}
```

Then add the tableRef prop to your Material Table

```
<MaterialTable
    tableRef={this.state.tableRef}
    />
```

Then on the `onRowClick` prop/function use tableRef to access `dataManager` and `onSelectionChange`

```
<MaterialTable
    tableRef={this.state.tableRef}
    onRowClick={(event, rowData) => {
        // Update the clicked rows checked state
        rowData.tableData.checked = !rowData.tableData.checked;

        // pass dataManager the current rows checked state and path/ID, the path/ID needs to be an array, ex: [1]
        this.state.tableRef.current.dataManager.changeRowSelected(
           rowData.tableData.checked,
           [rowData.tableData.id]
        );

        // call the onSelectionChange and pass it the row selected to ensure it updates your selection properly for any custom onSelectionChange functions.
        this.state.tableRef.current.onSelectionChange(rowData);
    }}
    />
```

Comment: Thank you Caleb! One note for anybody finding this later: if you are dealing with tree data you want to pass rowData.tableData.path to changeRowSelected as the second argument.